# How do I convert strings to utf-8 that are in a latin-1 field but where originally another charset in a MySQL SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got a table with lots of texts in different languages. The table and all the fields are `iso-8859-1`. The data that is in the fields was encoded in different charsets before it was inserted. It was not converted to `latin1`, so it often shows up as gibberish. It can be one of these:

- `iso-8859-1`
- `iso-8859-7`
- `windows-1250`
- `windows-1251`
- `windows-1254`
- `windows-1257`

I know which column maps to which kind of encoding.

What I would like to do is convert them to `utf-8` when I select them, in a way that they will not show up as gibberish in the final output.

My idea was to use `CONVERT()`, but [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-convert.html) are only talking about converting a string to another encoding. The string's encoding seems to be taken from the field's encoding. But that's broken for me.

Here's an example of what data looks like if I look at it directly in the DB.

```
Ðàä³àëüíà øèíà ïðèçíà÷åíà äëÿ áåçäîð³ææÿ.Ñïåö³àëüíî äëÿ Land Rover
```

This is supposed to be Ukranian and was encoded in `cp1251` before being put into the `latin1` field. If I simply `SELECT foo FROM bar` it without any conversion and display it to a webbrowser, telling it to use `cp1251` it will show up correctly as cyrillic text in the browser.

What I think I need to do now is ignore the fact that the field is `latin1` and convert from `cp1251` to `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

However, this is not doing what I want:

```
select convert(foo_ua using 'cp1251') from mytable;
```

It comes out as this, so the `latin1` is obviously still in there.

```
????????? ???? ?????????? ??? ??????????.?????????? ??? Land Rover
```

I tried `CAST()` as well, but to the same result. How do I tell it to ignore the `latin1` and just convert to `cp1251`, and how do I go to `utf8` from there?